# Column without member

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hbm2ddl

Using Hibernate we're trying to have it create an additional column to an abstract class - but we can't add a new member to this class (memory consumption in large scale). We need to have Hibernate create the schema (development phase, `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update`).

Let's say we have a **MyClass** entity class with members **a,b,c**, and we would like Hibernate to also create a column **d**. This column is not needed in memory and will be accessed only via HQL/SQL during saving/loading times of **MyClass** instances.

Can this be done?

Notes:
 1. Hibernate 3.6.0 Final + Oracle 11g + pure Java
 2. We use annotations, no xml files

Answer (score 1):

Add the property to the class, but make it lazy (using the `@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` annotation).

Make sure your classes are instrumented at build time: it's needed for this to work. More details are available in [this chapter of the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#performance-fetching-lazyproperties).

Comment: This will prevent eager fetching of the property, but still one needs to declare the property `MyClass.d` (in OPs example). The in-memory size of MyClass instances do increase by the addition of property `d`.

Comment: Hi JB Nizet, thanks for answering, but as binil said it would still require a new member to the `MyClass`, taking much memory...

Comment: Have you actually measured the difference in memory usage that this simple field would incur? This seems like premature optimization to me.