# Using Hibernate HQL, how can I add a column to a table?

Tags: hibernate, hql

Following a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145773/column-without-member), I would like to add an *int* column to a table **without** adding an *int* member to the class. This will only be used when loading/saving mass-scale instances. We don't want this *int* in memory.

Given a `MyClass` entity - how can I add a `MyIntColumn` to its table?

Notes:
- Hibernate 3.6.0 Final + Oracle 11g + Java pure
- Using annotations

Thanks,
- 10 of a Kind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to let hibernate create your schema you'd have to create a class member. What you can do is run a direct SQL query (not via HQL) that will alter your table and add the desired column. The problem here is that hibernate won't be able to use this column unless you define a class member for it - so unless you are going to use direct SQL or let Oracle manage this column (by default values, triggers etc.) you cannot do much with this column.